# How to wrap for loop in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been stuck on this silly thing, I can't figure out how to wrap my for loop inside of a div.

```
for (item = 0; item < event.length; item++) {
        var ID = event[item].id;
        element.find(".title").after("<span class='id'><img src='/avatar/" +ID+ "'/></span>");
        }
```

I want to achive this:

```
<div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Any Help is much apprciated.

Comment: `event.[item].id` should be `event[item].id`. But anyway, are you saying the div already exists on the page and you want to append spans to it using the loop?

Comment: That was a typo, thank you for pointing it out. spans exist I want to wrap them in a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
// a variable for the dynamically created span
var spanString = "";
for (item = 0; item < event.length; item++) {
  var ID = event[item].id;
  // new string will con cat wit the spanString
  spanString += ("<span class='id'><img src='/avatar/" + ID + "'/></span>");
}

// append the spanString to the `div.title`
$(".title").append($(spanString))
```

Comment: Beat me to it :-)
I just want to point out that you need to be careful that ID is properly HTML escaped, to avoid injection attacks

Comment: You should mark this answer as correct if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
//Assume sample event array 
var event = [1, 2, 3];
for (item = 0; item < event.length; item++) {
    var ID = event[item];
    $("<span class='id'><img src='/avatar/" +ID+ "'/></span<br>").appendTo('#name');
  };
});
```

Considering sample HTML Below

```
<div id="name">
   hello
</div>
```

This way you can populate content inside the div